# Error when trying to build a custom julia system image on Windows

Tags: python, julia

I want to build a custom julia .dll in order to speed up the initialization of some custom julia code that I am calling from a python wrapper. I followed the instructions on this page: https://pyjulia.readthedocs.io/en/latest/sysimage.html and ran the command

```
python -m julia.sysimage sys.dll
```

but I get this error

```
Activating new environment at `C:\Users\KENNET~2\AppData\Local\Temp\tmp.pyjulia.sysimage.ns0yrrt6\compiler_env\Project.toml`
[ Info: Installing PackageCompiler...
   Updating registry at `C:\Users\kenneth39080\.julia\registries\General`
  Resolving package versions...
Updating `C:\Users\kenneth39080\AppData\Local\Temp\tmp.pyjulia.sysimage.ns0yrrt6\compiler_env\Project.toml`
  [9b87118b] + PackageCompiler v1.2.4
Updating `C:\Users\kenneth39080\AppData\Local\Temp\tmp.pyjulia.sysimage.ns0yrrt6\compiler_env\Manifest.toml`
  [9b87118b] + PackageCompiler v1.2.4
  [2a0f44e3] + Base64
  [ade2ca70] + Dates
  [b77e0a4c] + InteractiveUtils
  [76f85450] + LibGit2
  [8f399da3] + Libdl
  [56ddb016] + Logging
  [d6f4376e] + Markdown
  [44cfe95a] + Pkg
  [de0858da] + Printf
  [3fa0cd96] + REPL
  [9a3f8284] + Random
  [ea8e919c] + SHA
  [9e88b42a] + Serialization
  [6462fe0b] + Sockets
  [cf7118a7] + UUIDs
  [4ec0a83e] + Unicode
┌ Error: build.log for PackageCompiler [9b87118b-4619-50d2-8e1e-99f35a4d4d9d] not found
└ @ Main C:\Users\kenneth39080\Miniconda3\Lib\site-packages\julia\install-packagecompiler.jl:19
[ Info: Loading PackageCompiler...
[ Info: PackageCompiler is successfully installed at C:\Users\KENNET~2\AppData\Local\Temp\tmp.pyjulia.sysimage.ns0yrrt6\compiler_env
 Activating environment at `C:\Users\KENNET~2\AppData\Local\Temp\tmp.pyjulia.sysimage.ns0yrrt6\compiler_env\Project.toml`
[ Info: Loading PackageCompiler...
[ Info: Installing PyCall...
 Activating new environment at `C:\Users\KENNET~2\AppData\Local\Temp\tmp.pyjulia.sysimage.ns0yrrt6\Project.toml`
   Updating registry at `C:\Users\kenneth39080\.julia\registries\General`
  Resolving package versions...
Updating `C:\Users\kenneth39080\AppData\Local\Temp\tmp.pyjulia.sysimage.ns0yrrt6\Project.toml`
  [438e738f] + PyCall v1.92.1
Updating `C:\Users\kenneth39080\AppData\Local\Temp\tmp.pyjulia.sysimage.ns0yrrt6\Manifest.toml`
  [8f4d0f93] + Conda v1.5.0
  [682c06a0] + JSON v0.21.1
  [1914dd2f] + MacroTools v0.5.6
  [69de0a69] + Parsers v1.0.15
  [438e738f] + PyCall v1.92.1
  [81def892] + VersionParsing v1.2.0
  [2a0f44e3] + Base64
  [ade2ca70] + Dates
  [8f399da3] + Libdl
  [37e2e46d] + LinearAlgebra
  [d6f4376e] + Markdown
  [a63ad114] + Mmap
  [de0858da] + Printf
  [9a3f8284] + Random
  [9e88b42a] + Serialization
  [4ec0a83e] + Unicode
[ Info: Compiling a temporary system image without `PyCall`...
[ Info: PackageCompiler: creating system image object file, this might take a while...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\users\kenneth39080\miniconda3\lib\runpy.py", line 194, in _run_module_as_main
    return _run_code(code, main_globals, None,
  File "c:\users\kenneth39080\miniconda3\lib\runpy.py", line 87, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "c:\users\kenneth39080\miniconda3\Scripts\julia-py.exe\__main__.py", line 7, in <module>
  File "c:\users\kenneth39080\miniconda3\lib\site-packages\julia\julia_py.py", line 151, in main
    julia_py(**vars(parse_args(args, **kwargs)))
  File "c:\users\kenneth39080\miniconda3\lib\site-packages\julia\julia_py.py", line 74, in julia_py
    api.jl_atexit_hook(code)
OSError: exception: stack overflow
ERROR: LoadError: failed process: Process(`'c:\users\kenneth39080\miniconda3\Scripts\julia-py.exe' --color=yes --startup-file=no --cpu-target=native '--sysimage=C:\Users\kenneth39080\AppData\Local\Programs\Julia 1.5.3\lib\julia\sys.dll' --project=. '--output-o=C:\Users\KENNET~2\AppData\Local\Temp\jl_1uL7ce65to.o' -e 'Base.reinit_stdio()
@eval Sys BINDIR = ccall(:jl_get_julia_bindir, Any, ())::String
@eval Sys STDLIB = "C:\\Users\\kenneth39080\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Julia 1.5.3\\share\\julia\\stdlib\\v1.5"
Base.init_load_path()
if isdefined(Base, :init_active_project)
    Base.init_active_project()
end
Base.init_depot_path()
# This @eval prevents symbols from being put into Main
@eval Module() begin
    PrecompileStagingArea = Module()
    for (_pkgid, _mod) in Base.loaded_modules
        if !(_pkgid.name in ("Main", "Core", "Base"))
            eval(PrecompileStagingArea, :(const $(Symbol(_mod)) = $_mod))
        end
    end
    precompile_statements = String[]
        append!(precompile_statements, readlines("C:\\Users\\KENNET~2\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\jl_1gGb5xu3ra"))

    for statement in sort(precompile_statements)
        # println(statement)
        # The compiler has problem caching signatures with \`Vararg{?, N}\`. Replacing
        # N with a large number seems to work around it.
        statement = replace(statement, r"Vararg{(.*?), N} where N" => s"Vararg{\1, 100}")
        try
            Base.include_string(PrecompileStagingArea, statement)
        catch
            # See julia issue #28808
            @debug "failed to execute $statement"
        end
    end
end # module
empty!(LOAD_PATH)
empty!(DEPOT_PATH)
'`, ProcessExited(1)) [1]

Stacktrace:
 [1] pipeline_error at .\process.jl:525 [inlined]
 [2] run(::Cmd; wait::Bool) at .\process.jl:440
 [3] run at .\process.jl:438 [inlined]
 [4] create_sysimg_object_file(::String, ::Array{String,1}; project::String, base_sysimage::String, precompile_execution_file::Array{String,1}, precompile_statements_file::Array{String,1}, cpu_target::String, script::Nothing, isapp::Bool) at C:\Users\kenneth39080\.julia\packages\PackageCompiler\KeZOk\src\PackageCompiler.jl:307
 [5] create_sysimage(::Array{Symbol,1}; sysimage_path::String, project::String, precompile_execution_file::Array{String,1}, precompile_statements_file::Array{String,1}, incremental::Bool, filter_stdlibs::Bool, replace_default::Bool, cpu_target::String, script::Nothing, base_sysimage::Nothing, isapp::Bool) at C:\Users\kenneth39080\.julia\packages\PackageCompiler\KeZOk\src\PackageCompiler.jl:443
 [6] (::var"#1#2")(::String) at C:\Users\kenneth39080\Miniconda3\Lib\site-packages\julia\compile.jl:27
 [7] mktempdir(::var"#1#2", ::String; prefix::String) at .\file.jl:709
 [8] mktempdir(::Function, ::String) at .\file.jl:707 (repeats 2 times)
 [9] top-level scope at C:\Users\kenneth39080\Miniconda3\Lib\site-packages\julia\compile.jl:24
 [10] include(::Function, ::Module, ::String) at .\Base.jl:380
 [11] include(::Module, ::String) at .\Base.jl:368
 [12] exec_options(::Base.JLOptions) at .\client.jl:296
 [13] _start() at .\client.jl:506
 [14] #invokelatest#1 at .\essentials.jl:710 [inlined]
 [15] invokelatest(::Any) at .\essentials.jl:709
 [16] top-level scope at none:1
in expression starting at C:\Users\kenneth39080\Miniconda3\Lib\site-packages\julia\compile.jl:23
Command '['C:\\Users\\kenneth39080\\Miniconda3\\Scripts\\julia-py.exe', '--julia', 'julia', '--compiled-modules=no', '--color=yes', 'C:\\Users\\kenneth39080\\Miniconda3\\Lib\\site-packages\\julia\\compile.jl', 'C:\\Users\\KENNET~2\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\tmp.pyjulia.sysimage.ns0yrrt6\\compiler_env', 'C:\\Users\\kenneth39080\\Miniconda3\\Lib\\site-packages\\julia\\precompile.jl', 'C:\\Users\\kenneth39080\\sys.dll', '']' returned non-zero exit status 1.
```

I notice that the documentation says the the custom system image build command is not tested on Windows so that might have somethin to do with it. However I haven't been able to find any record of anybody else having this exact issue so I wonder if I am doing something wrong?